# Return the Modulo of negative numbers in a vector R

Tags: r, vector, numbers

Is there a simple function in `R {base}` to return the modulus of negative numbers?

I was looking for something like:

```
v <- c(1, -2, 3, -4)

module(v)

#> [1]  1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Just a note that in American English, the modulus of a real number is usually called the absolute value, and the function is called abs in most programming languages. (But we do use the word "modulus" for complex numbers, e.g. the modulus of 3+4i is 5.) Some of those who down-voted this question may have been unaware that the word "modulus" sometimes means the absolute value.

Comment: Thank you @DaveRadcliffe. I'm not an English native speaker as you can tell. I believe most Brazilians like myself are more familiar with the word modulus in this context, that's the origin of my confusion. Thanks to your comment, it is now clear to me how modulus and absolute value are the same thing, making the function `abs()` much more intuitive. I hope more SO users would comment to justify downvotes and perhape be more aware of language and cultural differences. Thanks again!

Comment: * perhaps. Typos are all my fault :)

Comment: @DaveRadcliffe , exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
abs(v)
```

This gives you the modulus from a vector v.